# How can i connect my django like button to ajax to refresh automatically

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I have a  django project that im working on. Users will be able to like and dislike post.

models.py

```
class Tweet(models.Model):
    tweet_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tweet_message = models.TextField()
    tweet_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    tweet_like_counter = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    tweet_picture = models.FileField(null=True,blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.tweet_message


class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    tweet = models.ForeignKey(Tweet, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.tweet.tweet_message

class Disike(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    tweet = models.ForeignKey(Tweet, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.tweet.tweet_message
```

views.py

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
@csrf_exempt
@login_required
def like(request, pk):
    currentTweet = get_object_or_404(Tweet,pk=pk)
    username = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
    like_queryset = Like.objects.filter(tweet=currentTweet, user=username)
    dislike_queryset = Disike.objects.filter(tweet=currentTweet, user=username)


    if like_queryset.exists():
        Like.objects.filter(tweet=currentTweet, user=username).delete()
        dislikeobject = Disike.objects.filter(tweet=currentTweet).count()
        likeobject = Like.objects.filter(tweet=currentTweet).count()
        currentTweet.tweet_like_counter = likeobject - dislikeobject
        currentTweet.save()

    if dislike_queryset.exists():
        Disike.objects.filter(tweet=currentTweet, user=username).delete()
        dislikeobject = Disike.objects.filter(tweet=currentTweet).count()
        likeobject = Like.objects.filter(tweet=currentTweet).count()
        currentTweet.tweet_like_counter = likeobject - dislikeobject
        currentTweet.save()


    like = Like.objects.create(tweet=currentTweet)
    like.user.add(username)
    dislikeobject = Disike.objects.filter(tweet=currentTweet).count()
    likeobject = Like.objects.filter(tweet=currentTweet).count()
    currentTweet.tweet_like_counter = likeobject - dislikeobject
    currentTweet.save()

    return JsonResponse({
        'like_counter': currentTweet.tweet_like_counter
    })


@csrf_exempt
@login_required
def dislike(request, pk):
    currentTweet = get_object_or_404(Tweet, pk=pk)
    username = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
    like_queryset = Like.objects.filter(tweet=currentTweet, user=username)
    dislike_queryset = Disike.objects.filter(tweet=currentTweet, user=username)

    if dislike_queryset.exists():
        Disike.objects.filter(tweet=currentTweet, user=username).delete()
        dislikeobject = Disike.objects.filter(tweet=currentTweet).count()
        likeobject = Like.objects.filter(tweet=currentTweet).count()
        currentTweet.tweet_like_counter = likeobject - dislikeobject
        currentTweet.save()

    if like_queryset.exists():
        Like.objects.filter(tweet=currentTweet, user=username).delete()
        dislikeobject = Disike.objects.filter(tweet=currentTweet).count()
        likeobject = Like.objects.filter(tweet=currentTweet).count()
        currentTweet.tweet_like_counter = likeobject - dislikeobject
        currentTweet.save()

    dislike = Disike.objects.create(tweet=currentTweet)
    dislike.user.add(username)
    dislikeobject = Disike.objects.filter(tweet=currentTweet).count()
    likeobject = Like.objects.filter(tweet=currentTweet).count()
    currentTweet.tweet_like_counter = likeobject - dislikeobject
    currentTweet.save()

    return JsonResponse({
        'like_counter':  currentTweet.tweet_like_counter

    })
```

template

```
 <p class='id{{ post.tweet_user }}' name="tweetlikes" class="card-text" style="background-color: lightgray;"><strong>{{ post.tweet_like_counter }} likes </strong></p>

<form   id="like{{ post.tweet_user }}" method="POST" name="likeform" action="{% url 'like' pk=post.pk %}"   style="float:left;">
          {% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit" class="like-form" name="like" class="btn btn-primary" >Like</button>
</form>

<script>
       $('#like{{ post.tweet_user }}').on('submit', function(event){
           event.preventDefault();
                             var oldVal =  parseInt($(".id{{ post.tweet_user }}").text())
        var url = $('#like{{ post.tweet_user }}').attr('action');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:url,
            data:{
                'like_counter':oldVal
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(data){
                $(".id{{ post.tweet_user }}").html(data.like_counter + " " +  "likes");
            }
        })
    })
</script>

<form   id="dislike{{ post.tweet_user }}" name="dislikeform" method="POST" action="{% url 'dislike' pk=post.pk %}" style="float:right;" >
          {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary">Dislike</button>
</form>

<script>
   $('#dislike{{ post.tweet_user }}').on('submit', function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
                             var oldVal =  parseInt($(".id{{ post.tweet_user }}").text())
        var url = $('#dislike{{ post.tweet_user }}').attr('action');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url:url,
            data:{
                'like_counter':oldVal
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(data){
                $(".id{{ post.tweet_user }}").html(data.like_counter + " " +  "likes");
            }
        })
    })
</script>
</div>
```

The problem lies in my ajax. The functionality of my website works great. Its just the ajax. When A user clicks the like button on the first post, it allows the user to only like the button one time Like it should. When another user makes a post (which makes two post on the page), the button post like buttons dont work anymore, and it changes the like number tag, and also it makes the data comes out diffent. Help please?

Comment: Why are users linked to likes/dislikes with `ManyToManyField`? Can a single "like" be shared among users? `ForeignKey` would work fine here.

Answer (score 0):

Why are users linked to likes/dislikes with `ManyToManyField`? Can a single "like" be shared among users? `ForeignKey` would work fine here.

Also, since your code state that a user cannot have `Like` and `Dislike` on the same "tweet" both at the same time, I suggest you to collapse these two models into one with `Boolean` or numeric field meaning `+1` or `-1`.

Instead of turturing database with that many queries you could use `[update_or_create][1]` and [F()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) or [Subquery()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) expression, or [Count/Sum](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) aggregation. The latter will also fix race conditions issue in update queries.

```
def like(request, pk):
    Like.objects.update_or_create(tweet_id=pk, user=request.user, 
        defaults={"value": <+1/-1>})
    Tweet.objects.filter(pk=pk, ).annotate(likes_count=Sum(tweet__like__value), ).\
        update(tweet_like_counter=F(likes_count), )
    like_counter = Tweet.objects.values_list('tweet_like_counter', flat=True).get(pk=pk,)

    return JsonResponse({
        'like_counter': like_counter
    })
```

The first statement will create or update if it exists a Like object with user_id and tweet_id. Note, `user` value already exists in `request` object so you don't need to make additional queries to achieve it.
Also you don't need to instantiate a `Tweet` object with given tweet_id (equal to `pk` arg) - pk/tweer_id is enough here.

The next statement will update `tweet_like_counter` based on aggregation of all existent likes/dislikes. And this update performs a single SQL command instead of 4 commands in your code: get Tweet object, get two counters, save Tweet object with new counter.

Statement three will retrieve current `like_counter`. Note, it selects [a single column](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) instead of instantiating full `Tweet` object.